# DOMDocument::load : Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php

This error is thrown when calling `DomDocument.load('./the/path/to/the/'.$this->image);` however when I use the absolute path instead of an instance variable, the issue goes away, i.e. `DomDocument.load('./the/path/to/the/image.png');`. I'm running it locally on a windows box so I don't think ownership is an issue.

Comment: i think there is some problem with your variable try to print it out see

Comment: ...It is indeed `NULL`, I'll update when I've found the culprit.

Comment: ...Turned out to be a syntax error, I used `$this->$fileName` insteda of `$this->fileName` ... AAAARRRRGGGGGG!!!!